# Where is my no-ip installation?

Tags: files

I just installed `noip` from the source code, however now I cannot find it. I need to configure it still and I fear it's broadcasting rogue somewhere with the wrong information.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you did to install it?

Answer (score 0):

If the installation procedure is not customized, the binary is at

```
/usr/local/bin/noip2
```

The configuration is at

```
/usr/local/etc/no-ip2.conf
```

You can find more information in `README.FIRST`, which should be in `noip` source directory.